# Array elements lose their keys after calling array_values()

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I am having an issue getting the inner array key/value pairs correctly. I have the outer array correct but the inner arrays just have index numbers as keys instead of me setting the key to what I am wanting. Seems like I'm missing a step in the formation of the inner array but I'm not sure what it is.

My current code now:

```
$path = './downloads/Current/v5.5/';
$blacklist = array('orig55205Web', 'SQL Files', '.', '..');

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $folder) {
    if($folder->isDot() || in_array($folder, $blacklist)) continue;

    if($folder->isDir()) {
        $item = $folder->getFilename();
        $versions[$item] = array();
        
        if ($handle = opendir($path . $item)) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
                    array_push($versions[$item], $file);
                }
                asort($versions[$item]);
                $versions[$item] = array_values($versions[$item]);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
ksort($versions);
print_r($versions);
```

My output looks like this currently:

```
Array
(
    [55106Web] => Array
        (
            [0] => 55106.txt
            [1] => ClientSetup.exe
            [2] => ClientSetup32.exe
            [3] => Setup.exe
            [4] => Setup32.exe
        )

    [55122Web] => Array
        (
            [0] => 55122.txt
            [1] => ClientSetup.exe
            [2] => ClientSetup32.exe
            [3] => Setup.exe
            [4] => Setup32.exe
        )
 )
```

What i WANT it to output:

```
Array
(
    [55106Web] => Array
        (
            [Version] => 55106.txt
            [CS64] => ClientSetup.exe
            [CS32] => ClientSetup32.exe
            [S64] => Setup.exe
            [S32] => Setup32.exe
        )

    [55122Web] => Array
        (
            [Version] => 55122.txt
            [CS64] => ClientSetup.exe
            [CS32] => ClientSetup32.exe
            [S64] => Setup.exe
            [S32] => Setup32.exe
        )
 )
```

Comment: Can you show what you want the output to be?

Comment: Sorry about that Patrick Q, forgot the output piece

Comment: Remove `array_values()` call

Comment: That just changes the sorting of the keys, instead i want to name the keys something specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.  First, you're not doing anything that assigns string-based indexes to the inner array.

Second, even if you were, those indexes would be removed as a result of your use of [array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values)  From the docs `array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.`

So you should assign the indexes (see below), and remove the call to `array_values`.

This may not exactly suit your needs 100%, but should get you going in the right direction.

```
$indexesArray = array("Version", "CS64", "CS32", "S64", "S32");
$i = 0;
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
        $versions[$item][$indexesArray[$i]] = $file;
        $i++
    }
}
asort($versions[$item]);
```

Comment: That doesnt solve my issue with being able to name the keys. Instead of numerical keys i want the name the key something specific

Comment: @user1784477 "i want the name the key something specific"  So add that to your code.  Right now, there's nothing in there that attempts to specify the index.  i.e. Where are you getting `Version`, `CS64`, `CS32`, etc? Where are you trying to assign those as indexes?

Comment: right now the 'version, etc..' values will be hardcoded but im assuming that i need to have the index name set during this step? `array_push($versions[$item], $file);`

Comment: I havent written anything to handle the naming yet, i have been stuck on getting the key name set in the first place..

Comment: Causes errors with `array_push` because requiring parameters `array_push($versions[$item][$i], $file);` instead of `array_push($versions[$item][$i] = $file);` Where does $indexesArray come into play?

Comment: @user1784477 Bah, sorry about that.  Meant to remove the `array_push`.  Check it now.

Comment: OK i dont get the errors any longer but im also not getting the key name assigned, its still just 0-4. Am i right to assume that the [$i] in `$versions[$item][$i] = $file;` is trying to assign the value of the key index for the inner array?

Comment: I am trying to use array_combine() to combine $indexesArray and $versions[$item]?

Comment: @user1784477 Not sure where my brain is today.  Made another edit.